# SpringBootApplication не работает в полной версии tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, war

выполняю первый guide с сайта Spring: "Building a RESTful Web Service"  с 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch

Делал в IntelliJ IDEA (это мое первое знакомство с Spring и Idea). Успешно все запускается и работает на встроенном tomcat, так же успешно запускается исполняемый jar файл,  но на шаге когда сделал war файл,  выложил его в tomcat/webbapps/  - томкат этот  файлик распаковал,  но когда пытаюсь зайти на http://localhost:8080/greeting     выдается ошибка 404.  Единственное что я заметил из того что мне знакомо - нет файла web.xml в папке WEB-INF.

По гайду я выполнил все инструкции([92.1 Create a Deployable War File](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)):
в pom.xml  добавлено

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

и

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

далее  класс Application  изменил как требовалось:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

И собственно war файл создавал в командной строке командой *mvn clean package*.
Что надо сделать чтобы работало на отдельном сервере Tomcat?

Comment: можно вопрос, зачем спринг-бут если вы все равно руками кладете это в томкат?

Comment: к сожалению я не способен ответить на Ваш вопрос, ввиду некомпетенции.  Я лишь хотел  посмотреть как это все работает,  и ранее слышал war файлы можно "скармливать" Томкату.  :)

Comment: Спринг бут был создан для того, чтобы все работало без внешнего веб сервера, в принципе то что Вы хотите сделать возможно - но это достаточно странная ситуация

Comment: буду признателен если подскажете как. Гугл сказал, что можно обойтись и без web.xml  с сервлетами 3.0 и выше,  кои и имеются,  но приводимые инструкции мне непонятны.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы создать war-файл вам потребуется [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/).(в вашем guide он добавлен в `pom`).

Далее создаете новую 'Run/Debug Configuration' для 'Maven':
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Указываем директорию проекта.
2. Для командной строки указываем 'war:war'
3. Указываем что перед запуском необходимо собрать проект.

Естественно в `pom` должно быть указано:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

После запуска данной конфигурации в директории проекта должен быть создан war-файл вида `artifactId`-`version`.war

Comment: там же где и ранее создался gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war  я его кинул в томкат,  он его распаковал,  но все тоже самое - 404 , единственно war был ранее 16Мб, а сейчас 11Мб

Comment: @KROGOT88 и как вы к нему обращаетесь? http://localhost:8080/greeting так? если да, тогда попробуйте http://localhost:8080/<ВАШ_artifactId>/greeting

Comment: вот я дурак )))))   точно,  совсем забыл  указать  в адресе  имя приложения.  Зашел на http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting   и все зараотало. Спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Проверять  нужно не адресом  `http://localhost:8080/greeting`   , а  `http://localhost:8080/*webbapp_name*/greeting`.  В данном случае `http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting`
Спасибо ermak0ff